# Selenium 3 Firefox Profile

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium3, firefox-profile

Selenium Version : 3.3.1

I am trying to start up a windows node using the following command

```
java -role node -nodeConfig <%=@selenium_node %> -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile <%=@firefox_profile_directory %> -jar <%=@selenium_jar %>
```

I have put the `-D...` command line parameters before the `-jar` prompt as discussed here:

> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2566

However, I get the error:

> Unrecoginized opton: -role Error: Could not creacte the Java Virtual
>   Machine. Error: A fatal exception  has occurred.  Program will exit.

If I try the other way around e.g.

```
java -role node -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile <%=@firefox_profile_directory %> -nodeConfig <%=@selenium_node %>  -jar <%=@selenium_jar %>
```

or

`java -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile <%=@firefox_profile_directory %> -jar <%=@selenium_jar %> -role node -nodeConfig <%=@selenium_node %>`

I get the error:

> Could not find or load main class C:...\firefox\profile

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put only the -D options between java and -jar, all options should go after the .jar filename

```
java -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile <%=@firefox_profile_directory %> -jar <%=@selenium_jar %> -role node -nodeConfig <%=@selenium_node %>
```

Comment: I have tried this too.  I also get the same error `Could not find or load main class C:...\firefox\profile`

Comment: Put equals instead of space between option and argument?

Comment: I have also tried this `-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=<%=@firefox_profile_directory %>`  That too, did not work...